# Sum rows across subset of columns of 'object' type

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with too many to reproduce here, but the logic is as follows:

```
data = {'ID': ['12AX', '7YTQ','ZA77'],
        'Value_1': [19, 'Not applicable', 33],
        'Status': ['Not Applicable','Not Applicable','Not Applicable']
        'Value_2': [13,4,15],
        'Value_3': ['Not Applicable', 'Not Applicable', 102.7]
        'Category': ['AAA', 'AAA', 'BA']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am trying to create a new column called `Sum` using only a subset of the existing columns (let's say `Value_1`, `Value_2`, `Value_3`) and to ignore any text that might be in any of the rows. So for example, the `Sum` of the first row will be `19+13 = 32` and the string value in column `Value_3` is ignored since it says `Not Applicable`.

My function so far is this, but it either returns `None` or `0` and I can't figure out why.

```
def safe_sum(row):
    try:
        float_numbers = [float(x) for x in row if isinstance(x, (int, float))]

        return sum(float_numbers)

    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return None

df['Sum'] = df[['Value_1','Value_2','Value_3'].apply(safe_sum, axis=1)
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your function works ok

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works fine.

Another solution:

```
df.replace({'Not Applicable':0}, inplace=True)
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

And if you want only for subset of columns, you can change the last line to:

```
df['sum'] = df[['Value_1','Value_2','Value_3']].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: I think the OP only wants to sum a subset of columns.